# Client can not connect zu Server

Tags: java, intellij-idea, rmi, connectexception

im trying to connect a client to a server. The server is running, but when i try to connect the client i get this error: 
"Exp_Client cannot connect to Exp_Server. Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1.; nested exception is: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused"

[the method which should connect; the marked line does not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnnL4.png)

[the relevant constants](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXrJX.png)

- I turned off the firewall
- VM-Options are:
  -Djava.security.manager
  -Djava.security.policy=/Users/Max/Documents/Uni/Bachelor/Vertiefung/Bachelorarbeit/workspace/kit-iism-experimenttool/Exp_Implementation/java.policy
- Program arguments: none
- I use IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.5
- JRE: 1.60_65
- jdk1.7.0_79
- JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
- h2-1.3.176

Any ideas what the problem could be? 
Would be very thankful for help.
Kind regards, Max

Comment: likely cause: you're trying to connect to a port that's not listening. Check your port settings, check if the port is listening.

Comment: Running on the same machine only. With the emergence of IPv6 "::1" instead of "127.0.0.1" could be tried for the loop-back localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Just a few ideas:

- You have not started your server correctly.
- You are trying to connect to the wrong port.
- Your server is not waiting to accept connections.

Your source code would be great to have a look on

Comment: What does 'your server is not waiting to accept connections' mean? NB don't use code formatting for text that isn't code.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't started the RMI registry, or the URL isn't correct.